# Abnormal CPU load even after canceling build

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I'm using `Sublime Text 3` as a script editor. I by mistake made the following code in test.cpp in `C++`

```
int N = 10;
std::vector<int> a(N);
for (int i=0; i<N)
    a.push_back(i);
```

which should have been

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
```

And I builded and ran the code, and my `Sublime Text 3` was in an endless process of building my test.cpp. So I clicked `Tools -> Cancel build`, and my terminal showed my build was cancelled.

However, `my activity monitor` showed continuous CPU load consumption by my test.cpp, and I could not help but rebooted my computer.

How could I have stopped the whole procedure of test.cpp and started from the beginning? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you get in this state (and you already know how) ... If you are on Linux,  search for Task Manager, and 'kill' the executable (your's or maybe sublime).  Windows appears to have a TaskKill command, perhaps it is similar.